# Image does not show up (Lightbox)

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Lightbox doesn't work. Once the thumb is clicked, the page becomes dark but no image pops up. What could be the problem?

Head section:

```
<link href="/inc/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/inc/bootstrap/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/inc/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/inc/lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Code:

```
<a href="image.png" rel="lightbox" title="Some title"><img src="image-thumb.png"></a>
```

Right before `</body>`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/inc/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/inc/lightbox/js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: No, nothing in the console.

Comment: Try to set this scripts in head section and check result

Comment: Have you tried scrolling to the bottom or zooming out of the page? I think I had this problem in the past and the image just happened to be below everything. It's possibly a styling problem if it is.

Answer (score 0):

I already fix the problem.
Do not use the latest version of jquery, instead use version 1.7.2, like they use on the lightbox website example.